# What is the equivalent of boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock in STL?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, boost-thread

I'm trying to replace the boost functionalities with STL functinoalities in C++11.
There is a write function in my multi-thread application.

First, the function verifies the data. Next, writes to it.
There are two locks mentioned as mentioned below:

```
class Data
{
    mutable boost::mutex mut;
    void Data::Write()
    {
        boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> ulock(mut);
        // ... Verification statements

        boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(ulock);
        // ... Writing statements
    }
};
```

I'm a novice of boost functionalities. Can you please explain what it does and how I can achieve the functionality with STL features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 doesn't provide shared locks at all. C++14 does, but doesn't allow them to be upgraded to exclusive locks; you'd need a second mutex for that, something like:

```
mutable std::shared_timed_mutex read_mutex;
std::mutex write_mutex;

void Write() {
    std::shared_lock read_lock(read_mutex);
    // ... Verification statements

    std::lock_guard write_lock(write_mutex);
    // ... Writing statements
}
```

You'll need to take some care only to acquire the write lock while already holding the read lock, to avoid deadlocks. If you have a working Boost solution, it might be better to stick to that until the standard library provides equivalent functionality.

Comment: staying with boost is not an option for me. I've to remove it. I tried to test your solution. But couldn't put shared_timed_mutex in code. It is added only in C++14. Mine is C++ 11 :(

Comment: @Neo: If you can't use C++14, and you can't use Boost, then you can't use shared locks (unless you forget about C++ libraries and go straight to the native API). One of those three restrictions will have to go.

Comment: Re-add boost. :-)  It mixes in fine.

Comment: I think the proposed solution is not equivalent. `reader_lock` can be acquired while `write_lock` is held by another thread, which will not happen in the original code.

Comment: This is incorrect. There is no guarantee that things happen in write mutex will be seen in read mutex. So basically it is same effect with code that has no read lock at all. This is data race

Answer (score 0):

In C++ threads you get:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

mutex mu;

// lock_guard: acquire the mutex mu and lock it. when the lock_guard object goes out of scope, mutex is unlocked.
lock_guard<mutex> lock(mu);

// more flexible than the lock_guard
// http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock
unique_lock<mutex> ulock(mu);
ulock.unlock();
ulock.lock();
```

Comment: That was the case in C++11. But the question is about shared locks, introduced in C++14.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I think std::lock_guard can replace boost::unique_lock. But in this case, I'm looking for replacement of upgrade_lock and upgrade_to_unique_lock. I think when they mean upgrading, can get more preference while waiting for the critical section (correct me if I'm wrong). Is there any similar concept in STL?

Comment: @Neo: "Upgrading" means converting a shared lock to an exclusive lock. As far as I can see, that's not supported by the standard library yet (as of C++14). If you need that functionality, I guess you'll have to stick with Boost for now.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, sorry I forgot to mention the C++ version I'm interested in !! I'm C++11 for my project. So I prefer solutions in C++11 only